# Put figure-like caption on a breakable tcolorbox

Tags: floats, formatting, captions, tcolorbox

In my document, I have `tcolorbox`es containing large definitions that span from half a page to two pages. To reference these boxes in my main text, I would like to refer to them as I would for figures. For the smaller ones, I can embed them in a `figure` environment like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-3] % This normally contains some mathematical specifications.
\end{tcolorbox} 
\caption{small definition.}
\end{figure}
```

However, for the bigger ones, I need to have a *breakable* `tcolorbox`, and this doesn't work well inside a `figure` environment. Let me show what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] % Start the document with some text.

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1-8] % This normally contains some mathematical specifications.
\end{tcolorbox} 
\caption{big definition.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

See the image below to observe the weird result.

**My question**: Is it possible to add a caption below or above a breakable `tcolorbox`, in the same style as in a `figure` environment? A custom environment/caption numbering would be fine too. Preferably, the boxes that fit on one page should be floating. For the ones that span multiple pages, I don't think floats are appropriate anymore, so that is of less importance.

Note: I know captions for `tcolorbox`es are often simulated by using the `title` option. However, I would like to have a caption in the same style as a `figure`/`table`/..., that is above or below the box.

[image: weird result]

Comment: tcolorbox may be breakable, but figure isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caption` package has the macro `\captionof` that can be used for such cases to provide a float-like caption for non-floats. It should, however, placed inside a box, such as a `minipage`.

It uses the very same style as other captions and it will also take over the numbering of the floats. Therefore, you are able to mix real-float captions and non-float captions as you like.

So, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] % Start the document with some text.

%\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1-8] % This normally contains some mathematical specifications.
\end{tcolorbox} 
%\end{figure}
%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{big definition.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The last part of the output would then be something like:

[image]

I think, the macro is quite self-explanatory: The first argument takes the kind of float this non-float caption should imitate and the second argument takes the caption.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent a page break between the `tcolorbox` and the caption?